# How to remove a metabox from menu editor page?

Tags: php, functions, menus, metabox, hooks

I am not sure if it is much different for any page but I am wondering how to remove a metabox from the appearance>menu page without having to go into the wordpress core files and remove it. Is there something I can do to override it so it doesn't appear both on the page and on the screen options menu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By inspecting the file `/wp-admin/nav-menus.php` we can see that these meta-boxes:

[image: metaboxes]

are rendered with:

```
<?php do_meta_boxes( 'nav-menus', 'side', null ); ?>
```

The file `/wp-admin/includes/nav-menu.php` contains the corresponding `add_meta_box()` calls and from that we can construct the relevant removal code:

```
function custom_remove() {      
    remove_meta_box('nav-menu-theme-locations', 'nav-menus', 'side'); 
    remove_meta_box('add-custom-links', 'nav-menus', 'side'); 
    remove_meta_box('add-post', 'nav-menus', 'side'); 
    remove_meta_box('add-page', 'nav-menus', 'side'); 
    remove_meta_box('add-category', 'nav-menus', 'side'); 
}
add_action('admin_head-nav-menus.php', 'custom_remove');
```

where we can use for example the `admin_head-nav-menus.php` action since it is called before these meta-boxes are rendered.

If you have a custom post type (or a custom taxonomy) then you can remove it's meta-box with

```
   remove_meta_box( 'add-xxx' , 'nav-menus' , 'side' );
```

where `xxx` is the corresponding name.

You can further check out the functions `wp_nav_menu_setup()`, `wp_nav_menu_post_type_meta_boxes()` and `wp_nav_menu_taxonomy_meta_boxes()` to see how the meta-boxes are added.

Comment: Great! Thank you for the detailed answer I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!is_admin()) return;

// See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu_taxonomy_meta_boxes/
// $taxonomy_object is of type WP_Post_Type

add_filter('nav_menu_meta_box_object', function ($taxonomy_object) {

if (in_array($taxonomy_object->name, ['page', 'post', 'category'] )) {
  return null;
}

return $taxonomy_object;
```