# Remove metabox from WordPress menu editor page?

Tags: php, menus, wp-admin, hooks, metabox

I'm trying to remove meta boxes added to the WordPress menu editor page from a theme, but can't seem to figure out how to do it, I found [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97890/how-to-remove-a-metabox-from-menu-editor-page) answer, but I must be doing something wrong as it isn't working.

Below is what I want to remove:

[image]

**My code:**

```
add_action( 'do_meta_boxes', 'blm_remove_plugin_metaboxes' );

function blm_remove_plugin_metaboxes() {
    remove_meta_box('_menu_icon', 'nav-menus', 'side');
}
```

For the ID I have tried the following but none have worked:

- _menu_icon
- menu_icon
- add-_menu_icon
- add_menu_icon

Trying to find the code in the theme files that adds them, it appears they are utilising these hooks:

```
add_action( 'wp_nav_menu_item_custom_fields', array( __CLASS__, '_fields' ), 10, 4 );
add_action( 'wp_update_nav_menu_item', array( __CLASS__, '_save' ), 10, 3 );
add_filter( 'manage_nav-menus_columns', array( __CLASS__, '_columns' ), 99 );
```

The class method `_fields` appears to then call the respective method for the type of field and then echos that data.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Your code is not the same as the example, you use a wrong hook - should be `add_action('admin_head-nav-menus.php', 'blm_remove_plugin_metaboxes');`. Does this fix it already?

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that too; I got the `do_meta_boxes` hook from the comments section of the WP developer section for `remove_meta_box`. However, I have changed it, but no luck. Perhaps I am using the wrong ID?

Comment: Could be wrong ID, could also be that your code runs too soon (and the meta box isn't even added yet). For the latter, add a higher priority like `add_action('...', '...', 99999);`

Comment: @kero Didn't work either. I have also updated my question with some extra information.

Comment: The themes comes with a custom nav_menu_walker, and propably custom menu functions, which I suggest is the reason why your screenshots are not showing native WordPress meta boxes.

WordPress doesn't have a mega menu by default, so that functionality must come from the theme (or some plugin), adding these meta boxes. So, I would have a very deep look at the functions.php of the theme you are using and then examine, how the menu is build and then block/remove them in first place.